# Working with unix sockets doesn't return desired result

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to basically do server/client with UNIX sockets and workerman. I'm successfully starting the server. The socket file is created but I'm not sure how to make an actual connection to it and take/query the content from there.

The server looks like this

```
use \App;
use \DB;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$worker = new SeedDB();
$worker->load();

$api = new App('unix://' . __DIR__ . '/tmp.sock');
$api->count = 1; // process count

$api->get('/{name}', function ($requst, $name)   use ($worker) {

    $res =  $worker->get_db($name);
    return $res;
});

$api->start();
```

Here is the `App.php` the part which is for the server

```
/**
     * start
     */
    public function start()
    {
        $this->dispatcher = \FastRoute\simpleDispatcher(function (\FastRoute\RouteCollector $r) {
            foreach ($this->routeInfo as $method => $callbacks) {
                foreach ($callbacks as $info) {
                    $r->addRoute($method, $info[0], $info[1]);
                }
            }
        });

        \Workerman\Worker::runAll();
    }

    /**
     * @param TcpConnection $connection
     * @param Request $request
     * @return null
     */
    public function onMessage($connection, $request)
    {
        static $callbacks = [];
        try {
            $path = $request->path();
            $method = $request->method();
            $key = $method . $path;
            $callback = $callbacks[$key] ?? null;
            if ($callback) {
                $connection->send($callback($request));
                return null;
            }

            $ret = $this->dispatcher->dispatch($method, $path);
            if ($ret[0] === Dispatcher::FOUND) {
                $callback = $ret[1];
                if (!empty($ret[2])) {
                    $args = array_values($ret[2]);
                    $callback = function ($request) use ($args, $callback) {
                        return $callback($request, ...$args);
                    };
                }
                $callbacks[$key] = $callback;
                $connection->send($callback($request));
                return true;
            } else {
                $connection->send(new Response(404, [], '<h1>404 Not Found</h1>'));
            }
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            $connection->send(new Response(500, [], (string)$e));
        }
    }
```

And here is what I'm trying for the client part. It seems that instead to connect, I'm creating another one. Am I right?

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $time_start = microtime(true);

    try {
        // Get the search value from the request
        $search = $request->input('search');

        array_walk($search, function (&$resource) {
            $resource = new \Workerman\Worker('unix://' . __DIR__ . '/tmp.sock/' . $resource);
        });
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response($e->getMessage(), 500);
    }
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start);

    return view('search', compact('search', 'execution_time'));
}
```

The goal is to connect to the socket and take the result from DB. Any help is appreciated. With `Http:request` is working fine.

What is `print_r($search)` return is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Workerman\Worker Object
        (
            [id] => 0
            [name] => none
            [count] => 1
            [user] => 
            [group] => 
            [reloadable] => 1
            [reusePort] => 
            [onWorkerStart] => 
            [onConnect] => 
            [onMessage] => 
            [onClose] => 
            [onError] => 
            [onBufferFull] => 
            [onBufferDrain] => 
            [onWorkerStop] => 
            [onWorkerReload] => 
            [onWorkerExit] => 
            [transport] => tcp
            [connections] => Array
                (
                )

            [protocol] => 
            [_autoloadRootPath:protected] => /var/www/html/sw/app/Http/Controllers
            [_pauseAccept:protected] => 1
            [stopping] => 
            [_mainSocket:protected] => 
            [_socketName:protected] => unix:///var/www/html/sw/app/Http/Controllers/tmp.sock/admin
            [_localSocket:protected] => 
            [_context:protected] => Resource id #9
            [workerId] => 000000000000014a0000000000000000
        )
)
```

Which point to `unix:///var/www/html/sw/app/Http/Controllers/tmp.sock/admin` if I understand correctly? But the server is on `unix:///var/www/html/sw/tmp.sock`